# Dynamic Key Value Pair - Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am trying to set a key value pair in the HttpParams that has a dynamic key value, for example:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
properties.forEach(p => {
    params = params.appendAll({ p.id : p.value})
}
```

But the p.id does not work as it expects to receive a string. how can I accomplish such result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params = params.appendAll({ [p.id] : p.value})`

You need to bind it this way

Comment: if i wanted to add a text before setting up the dynamic id?
i.e. field-1 where the number 1 is the [p.id]

```params = params.appendAll({ 'field-1' : p.value})```

Is such thing possible?

Comment: In this case I'd advise doing building the key first in a variable and then adding it there
```const key = `field-${p.id}`;``` then do ```{[key]: p.value}``` if you can't already map before hand the keys

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly what you want is to add the value of the variable as the key to do so you should do:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
properties.forEach(p => {
    params = params.appendAll({ [p.id] : p.value})
}
```